# Using .Suffix in SortFieldDescriptor

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

My ASP.NET Web API has a Search method to search for a specific query in the Elasticsearch database. Also the user can set sort parameters like the property to sort by or if it should be ordered ascending or descending.

`http://localhost/api/search?query=jon&sortBy=lastname&sortOrder=desc`

The controller passes the request to Elasticsearch using NEST.

```cs
var sortProperty = typeof(T).GetProperty(options.SortBy, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

var sortOrder = options.SortOrder.IndexOf("desc", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
            ? SortOrder.Descending
            : SortOrder.Ascending;

var result = await this.elasticClient.SearchAsync<Person>(search => search
            .Query(q => q.MultiMatch(m => m
                    .Query(query)))
            .Sort(sort => sort.Field(sfd => sfd
                .Field(new Field(sortProperty))
                .Order(sortOrder)));
```

The `sortProperty` can be a text field, like *firstname* and *lastname* in this sample. To be able to sort by this text fields, I've added the "raw" keyword fields.

```json
{
    "people": {
        "mappings": {
            "person": {
                "properties": {
                    "birthdate": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "firstname": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "lastname": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have to add the suffix "raw" to the properties *firstname* and *lastname*.

```cs
.Sort(sort => sort.Descending(p => p.Firstname.Suffix("raw")));
```

But **how do I add this to the more generic version I used above**, where `sortProperty` and `sortOrder` are used to create the SortFieldDescriptor?

Something like the following does not work:

```cs
.Sort(sort => sort.Field(sfd => sfd
    .Field(new Field(sortProperty).Suffix("raw"))
    .Order(sortOrder)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Suffix()` is intended to be used with member expressions only.

I think you can make this easier by simply using a string to represent the field.

So, instead of

```
var sortProperty = typeof(T).GetProperty(options.SortBy, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
```

and using `PropertyInfo` to create an instance of `Field`, you could use

```
var sortOrder = options.SortOrder.IndexOf("desc", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
            ? SortOrder.Descending
            : SortOrder.Ascending;

var result = await this.elasticClient.SearchAsync<Person>(search => search
            .Query(q => q
                .MultiMatch(m => m
                    .Query(query)
                )
            )
            .Sort(sort => sort
                .Field(sfd => sfd
                    .Field($"{options.SortBy}.raw")
                    .Order(sortOrder)
                )
            );
```

Note that when instantiating a `Field` from a `string`, the string value is taken verbatim, so it needs to match the casing of the field in Elasticsearch. In contrast, expressions and `PropertyInfo` are transformed according to `.DefaultFieldNameInferrer()` on `ConnectionSettings`, which will camel case by default.

There are implicit conversions from `string`, `PropertyInfo` and `Expression<Func<T, object>>` to an instance of `Field`. Take a look at the [Field inference documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/field-inference.html).